# How to display json file data to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uicollectionview, nsdictionary

Here I tried to get data from my `URL` used base64,shaa256 for authorize Header and I just tried to display in my console. It's worked well. But  I need to convert to `NSDictionary` and to display to my `UICollectionView`. And my data having 3 `sections` with different data. Each section having 12 - 20 files.

**So my question are:**

1. How to convert my url to json to NSDictionary ?
2. Hoe to display with 3 section & each section should have 12 to 20 data files?
3. I used only this code in my viewdidload to get data.does i need to add `1.Connection did receive response 2.Connection did receive data 3.connection didFailWithError 4.connectionDidFinishLoading` to my code or don't want these 4 method to add in to my code

**Here is my code:**

I use to insert my below code to my above code after

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData 
                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSError * error;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:str 
                                                     options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                                       error: &error];

NSLog(@"%@",json);
```

But it din't work.if any useful answer for my 3 question is very useful for me.i am new to ios.help me out.Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data will most probably be JSON and not plain text? So convert the response straight to `NSDictionary`:

```
// show loading indicators when you are fetching data
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    // hide loading indicators when you received a response
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

    if (connectionError) {
        // Handle error
    } else {
        NSDictionary *jsonResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        NSLog(@"jsonResults: %@", jsonResults);
        // reload your views
        // [self.myCollectionView reloadData];
    }
}];
```

To make the collectionView with 3 sections you would need to have an NSArray containing the 3 sections, each of these 3 arrays would contain the 12-20 dictionaries with keys and values that will populate each cell.

```
NSArray *sectionOne = @[@{@"Section":@"1", @"Object":@"1"}, @{@"Section":@"1", @"Object":@"2"}];
NSArray *sectionTwo = @[@{@"Section":@"2", @"Object":@"1"}, @{@"Section":@"2", @"Object":@"2"}];
NSArray *sectionThree = @[@{@"Section":@"3", @"Object":@"1"}, @{@"Section":@"3", @"Object":@"2"}];
NSArray *collectionData = @[sectionOne, sectionTwo, sectionThree];

NSLog(@"collectionData: %@", collectionData);
```

Comment: yes this worked for me in console.But i am new to ios this is very first project.By using this NSDictionary how to shows it in collection view.I know to create collection view.But the very starting task to create key and value only i am asking..if any tutorial or projects that will be helpfull....

Comment: about my 3 question?? ---- should i use or no needed

Comment: No you dont have to add these delegate methods unless it is necessary? But I would suggest changing from `sendSynchronousRequest` to `sendAsynchronousRequest` and handle the response in a block. That way you can still manage the data and errors and it will be on a background thread.

Comment: i am not familar with that `sendSynchronousRequest to sendAsynchronousRequest`. Does it will make problem when i use NSDictionary to show data in my collection view??

Comment: No, it will be better.. I will update my answer. Just hang on 5mins :)

Comment: Actually your previous code i inserted in to my viewdidload method. Now what is the differece between your updated post. And  for handle error what should use ?----- to insert in to my view did load or any uialert should i use in that  comment area ( handle error)

Comment: To handle the error is up to you, you can retry the request, or try to handle known errors, or you can display the errors to the user with a `UIAlertView`. The difference between sync and async: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_synchronous_and_asynchronous_signalling

Comment: does i need to decode base64 to display data in my collection view